# Unable to accept string 'Quasar' in certain case

Tags: sql-server

I am having an issue which my table is not able to accept the word 'Quasar' as a string. It will give this error.

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.).

As it's just a `NVARCHAR` datatype column why is it not accepting 'Quasar' which is not even a keyword  nor has any special characters in the word?

Column Name = 'PickName' <- this column having the issue.

I post my table structure and also my insert script below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ConnoteTemplate](
    [TemplateNo] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CustNo] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CtrtNo] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CostCentreNo] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OperationHubNo] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PickName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PickADDR1] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [PickADDR2] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [PickADDR3] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [PickADDR4] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [PickContact] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PickDept] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PickTel1] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [PickTel2] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [PickPostal] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [PickDistNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DlvyName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DlvyADDR1] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [DlvyADDR2] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [DlvyADDR3] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [DlvyADDR4] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [DlvyContact] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DlvyDept] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DlvyTel1] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [DlvyTel2] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [DlvyPostal] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [DlvyDistNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CreateUser] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastEditUser] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [LastEditDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [ComputerName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [IPAddress] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


INSERT INTO [dbo].[ConnoteTemplate]([TemplateNo],[CustNo],[CtrtNo],[CostCentreNo],[OperationHubNo],[PickName],[PickADDR1],[PickADDR2],[PickADDR3],[PickADDR4],[PickContact],[PickDept],[PickTel1],[PickTel2],[PickPostal],[PickDistNo],[DlvyName],[DlvyADDR1],[DlvyADDR2],[DlvyADDR3],[DlvyADDR4],[DlvyContact],[DlvyDept],[DlvyTel1],[DlvyTel2],[DlvyPostal],[DlvyDistNo],[CreateUser],[CreateDateTime],[LastEditUser],[LastEditDateTime],[ComputerName],[IPAddress])
VALUES
(1,1,1,1,1,'Quasar','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','2020-01-22','',null,'','')
GO
```

Edited:

Long story short.... try running this query below and it will give you the error.

> SELECT CAST('Quasar' AS NVARCHAR(50))

Another funny thing is if you try to run this query below, it will post no issue.

> SELECT CAST('quasar' AS NVARCHAR(50))

I am using SSMS v 17.9.1/SQL Server 14.0.

Comment: You do realize that the number `1` is not a `NVARCHAR`, right? You need to pass the proper values to your `INSERT` statement. Pass the correct values in the proper format, and see if the error goes away. Why would you declare almost everything as an `NVARCHAR` in the first place?

Comment: @Irving Lee I don't see any issue with your CREATE and INSERT statements. But why did you conclude that its issue with that specific string - Quasar?

Comment: Per [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/SQL/comments/ese9nt/im_not_crazy_who_can_run_this_without_error_on/), it appears that the issue is network firewall related. _it appears that for whatever reason the binary string that gets returned from the server is being flagged as part of a spyware executable and being blocked by the firewall_

Comment: @KenWhite Hi Ken, ignore the rest of the columns. The Create tables and Insert query is not wrong. But when you Select from the table having the word 'Quasar' it will give you that error i'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.reddit.com/r/SQL/comments/ese9nt/im_not_crazy_who_can_run_this_without_error_on/

One of the comments:
“After discussing with the networking team and reviewing the traffic it appears that for whatever reason the binary string that gets returned from the server is being flagged as part of traffic from a spyware executable and being blocked by the firewall. It only happens on certain subnets because communications to them is routed through the firewall, while communication to the others is not.”

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and details to your answer. While it might answer the question, just adding some links does not help OP or future community members understand the issue or solution.

Comment: Thanks for the Link Rene. You have shine light upon my question.

Answer (score 0):

@Irving Lee, I don't see any issue with your CREATE and INSERT statements.

In general, we notice

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)

error when you disconnect from internet and try to execute the queries from same SSMS query window. Re-execute will normally execute them fine.

But why did you conclude that its issue with that specific string - "Quasar"?

Comment: Sorry Sam, my question is not clear enough. So after you Create Table and Insert the data. Try to select from the table and it will give you an error. Or try this   SELECT CAST('Quasar' AS NVARCHAR(50))

Comment: @IrvingLee We are also using SSMS v 17.9.1/SQL Server 14.0 and don't see issue. Like Rene G mentioned, it could be your network issue.

Comment: @sam, at first I too thought 'whadda heck', it's about connectivity. But, hey, nope... it IS indeed related to the word 'Quasar' being transmitted on the network :-)